# CNN-Bug Generell Questions

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

Im currently working on a little CNN with the Cifar-10 Dataset. I just updatet my code a little bit here and there and now it isnt working. I cant figure out the mistake. The prediction tells me "not an number". Couldnt find a answer for my proplem. So i cant post the Question without adding a little bit more text sooooo. Idk what i should write here. A good breakfast would be nice now. Coffe and Pancakes something like that. I hope i can poste the question now.

```
from keras.datasets import cifar10
import numpy as np

(x_training, y_training), (x_test,y_test) = cifar10.load_data()

x_training = x_training / 255.0
x_test = x_test / 255.0


%matplotlib inline

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.imshow(x_training[3])
plt.show


from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Flatten,Conv2D , MaxPooling2D, Dropout
import tensorflow as tf

model = Sequential()


model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3), input_shape=(32, 32, 3), activation="relu", padding="same"))
model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation="relu", padding="same"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation="relu", padding="same"))
model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation="relu", padding="same"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Conv2D(128, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation="relu", padding="same"))
model.add(Conv2D(128, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation="relu", padding="same"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(256, activation="relu"))
model.add(Dense(128, activation="relu"))
model.add(Dense(1, activation="sigmoid"))


model.compile(optimizer='RMSProp', loss="binary_crossentropy", metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()

model.fit(x_training, y_training,batch_size=128, epochs=10, shuffle = True )

model.evaluate(x_training, y_training)
results = model.predict(x_training[1].reshape(-1, 32, 32, 3))
results


class_names = ['airplane', 'automobile', 'bird', 'cat', 'deer',
               'dog', 'frog', 'horse', 'ship', 'truck']

max = np.max(results)
max_position = np.argmax(results)
class_name_predict = class_names[max_position]


plt.imshow(x_training[1])
plt.show

test = class_name_predict
test


plt.imshow(x_training[1])
plt.show


x = class_names[y_training[1][0]]
x
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some mistakes in your model:

The output layer for a multiclass problem must have a dimension equal to the number of classes with a softmax activation function

The standard losses for a multiclass problem are `categorical_crossentropy` and `sparse_categoricalcrossentropy`. `categorical_crossentropy` can be used when your target is one-hot encoded, `sparse_categoricalcrossentropy` is used when you have integer encoded labels (this is your case)

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3), input_shape=(32, 32, 3), activation="relu", padding="same"))
model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation="relu", padding="same"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation="relu", padding="same"))
model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation="relu", padding="same"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Conv2D(128, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation="relu", padding="same"))
model.add(Conv2D(128, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation="relu", padding="same"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(256, activation="relu"))
model.add(Dense(128, activation="relu"))
model.add(Dense(len(class_names), activation="softmax"))

model.compile(optimizer='RMSProp', loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy", metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()
```

[here the running notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/18mgBAVBmP3d8IlrxlIrxa_YXvewZK4xX?usp=sharing)

Comment: It worked thx. But i don't quite understand the output layer problem. So if im using filters that are stacked up over another i mostly have to make the last filter-layer look like this?

Comment: You can stack whatever you want but the last layer in a multiclass problem must have units/neurons equal to the number of classes and a softmax activation to reproduce probabilities